# Google Forms apps script accessing element by Id - no response - Won't add choices to item

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have the following snippet from a script that is bound to a google form. I am trying to add a choice and nothing is occurring when I open the form for editing. The MultipleChoice object in question already has 2 elements.

```
function onOpen(e) { 
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var ui = FormApp.getUi();
  var items = form.getItems();

  for (var i in items) {
    Logger.log(items[i].getTitle() + ': ' + items[i].getId());
  }

  var IsNewProject =  form.getItemById(2014691452);
  var newString = 'hey';
  Logger.log(IsNewProject.asMultipleChoiceItem.createChoice(newString))

  Logger.log(IsNewProject.asMultipleChoiceItem().getChoices().toString());
  //ui.alert("things are ok");

}
```

Logs Stuff

```
[16-05-30 16:02:10:107 EDT] Is this a new project?: 2014691452
[16-05-30 16:02:10:124 EDT] Project Title: 1585231066
[16-05-30 16:02:10:147 EDT] Project Description: 15525142
[16-05-30 16:02:10:161 EDT] Project Number: 934022512
[16-05-30 16:02:10:173 EDT] Thematic Priority: 280871288
[16-05-30 16:02:10:186 EDT] Description: 1909468645
[16-05-30 16:02:10:201 EDT] Choice
[16-05-30 16:02:10:226 EDT] Choice,Choice
```

Comment: Perhaps add some logger.log functions to see when/if it's called.

Comment: @Gerneio question edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `createChoice()` method creates a choice, but it doesn't add it to the item.  You need to use the `setChoices()` method, which takes choices as the parameter.

```
var newString = 'Buy Gadgets';

IsNewProject.setChoices([
  IsNewProject.createChoice(newString),
  IsNewProject.createChoice('Buy Widgets')
]);
```

The `id` parameter must be an integer.  You are using a string.

Currently:

```
form.getItemById('2014691452');
```

Should be:

```
form.getItemById(2014691452);
```

Comment: Same problem i'm afraid. Still is not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

The method `IsNewProject.asMultipleChoiceItem().getChoices()` returns an array of "choices objects", you need to get the value of these choices  using `getValue()`, see the [doc here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/choice)

final code :

```
var choices = IsNewProject.asMultipleChoiceItem().getChoices();
for(var n=0 ; n<choices.length ; n++){
   Logger.log(choices[n].getValue());
}
```